# Grub not getting modified when dual boot Fedora with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, grub2, dual-boot

I don't have windows. I dual boot between Fedora and Ubuntu. Somehow the grub gets modified only by Ubuntu, the modifications done to grub while being booted to Fedora does not show any effect after restart.

Is it possible to edit grub from both Ubuntu and Fedora installed in a system? Or we have to choose one and to be bound by it for any changes?

In my case somehow I can modify grub only from Ubuntu and when ever I do Fedora Kernel update (dnf offline upgrade method), the grub is built during the kernel update by Fedora. But it does not show up in the grub entries when I reboot. Only after booting to ubuntu if I do grub-update, I am able to see the new Fedora kernel.

How can I avoid this? I want both Ubuntu and Fedora to modify grub.

---

Note I have a separate efi partition shared by both ubuntu and fedora and separate `/boot` partitions one each for Ubuntu and Fedora.

```
$ lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
zram0                   252:0    0    8G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1                 259:0    0  1.8T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1             259:1    0  768M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2             259:2    0  768M  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p3             259:3    0  768M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4             259:4    0  128M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p5             259:5    0  1.8T  0 part
```

In above nvme0n1p2 is `/boot` for Fedora, nvme0n1p1 is `/boot` for Ubuntu.

Comment: Do not know about Fedora, but Ubuntu has a link to most current kernel that is updated with each new kernel. So you can add a boot entry that always works in Fedora's 40_custom. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen & 
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus & Read first post & jump to end for latest info. Most in link above.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205 But updates in grub will make that system first in UEFI boot order.

Comment: Two `/boot` pretty much means you have two sets of grub. If you use your *UEFI boot menu* to choose the Fedora grub, you should see the changes made to it(s boot menu) by Fedora.

Comment: @TomYan Can you post example with screenshots?

Comment: I think the key isn't a screenshot, but the keyboard key that leads you to the menu, which is machine-specific. You can try to look it up on your motherboard menu or so, or, alternatively, you can check out `efibootmgr` (which allows you to list the boot options and even set the transient "which to boot in the next boot" (`-n`) or change the persistent boot order.